# jquery passing an array to html form

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I have a two dimensional array:

If I 'alert' the output as follows I see expected results:

```
alert(myArray[0][0]['test']);
```

I am then passing the array to an html form:

```
$('form#id1 #PassArray').val(myArray);
```

I am then lisening for the form submission and if I do this:

```
var received=$('input#PassArray').val();

alert(received[0][0]['test']);
```

I get output: undefined.

Is it necessary to prepare the array in some way if passing it to a html form?

Comment: You can't set the value of an input box to an array

Comment: It's a hidden field of the array... so will I have to serialize?

Comment: Yes, even though its hidden, its still stored the same way normal inputs are

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, a form input can only have a string for its value.

You could either

1. Serialize your array into a string with [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)
2. Iterate over your array to assign values to individual form fields. The form fields can have the same name with `[]` appended to the end to treat them as an array, i.e. `<input name="array[]" />`
3. Just post the array with AJAX

Comment: Ok I see the issue at hand now, I have set the array_array as a session now so I can access it without having to pass it! Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a solid solution. np :D